# Can you echo code while on a different page

Tags: php, echo

Suppose I have an `upload.php` file. When the user clicks upload it goes to an `upload.inc.php` file to process the data input. While it is processing the input, is it possible to echo code to the `upload.php` file, such as a progress bar? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: With pure server-side PHP code alone it's not possible - that's a limitation of HTTP and browsers rather than PHP though really. But if you use JavaScript and AJAX to send the request to upload.inc.php then you can have a progress bar monitoring the file upload, yes. There are plenty of tutorials about it online already, including previous questions on this site. Do some searching.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to know if it's possible, and this comment helped me. Thanks

Comment: Specifically for PHP and file uploads, you might want to look into https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php regarding a progress indicator.